# Two Separate Powerpoints using a Projector?

Tags: powerpoint

What I want to do is to connect my laptop to a projector and make it an extension and while the extension (the projector) displays a the slideshow of my Powerpoint, a different slideshow is also displayed in my laptop. This is so I can look at my laptop showing the notes of my speech for each slide that I go to. I want it so that when I go to Slide 1 in the slideshow (displayed by the projector), the notes of my speech in slide 1 will be shown in my laptop. Is that possible? I can probably actually make a program for my needs but I want to know if there's already a way for that, and if none, what alternatives can be used to achieve a similar result?

Comment: Have you tried setting the projector to be one desktop view, and the laptop screen to be the other?

Comment: Well, I did say I made the projector an extension.

Comment: No, you said that is what you wanted to do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write notes in PowerPoint and then switch to "Presenter View".

This will show your slides on the external monitor and your notes + miniature previews of upcoming slides on the laptop screen.

See also http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/powerpoint-help/presenter-view-tools-for-running-a-powerpoint-presentation-HA001056547.aspx.

Comment: I think this answers my problem perfecty. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

you when connect to projector you must select extend mod(for example in Sony lab-tab press FN+F7 and select extend mod) and then in power point in slid show select monitor->double-monitor 
.
also in office 2013 when you connect to projector it automatic do Similar this.